# Vertical centering of a shrinked menu

Tags: html, css

I am building a responsive menu using only css and html. The only problem I have right now is that I don't know how to verticaly center the links in menu.

Here is my code:

```css
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      nav {

        display: none;

        width: 100%;

        height: auto;

        background: black;

        float: none;

        text-align: center;

        border-top: 1px solid white;

      }

      nav ul,

      li,

      a {

        width: 100%;

        display: inline-block;

        margin: 0 auto;

      }

      nav ul {

        padding-bottom: 5px;

        margin: 0 auto;

      }

      nav li {

        border-top: 1px solid white;

        line-height: 30px;

      }

    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
  </a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Reference</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Moje služby</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kdo jsem</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: A code snippet or jsfiddle would be tremendously helpful in solving your issue(s).

Comment: Out of interest do you know what @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) does?

Comment: Are you asking to test the op's knowledge or do you really not know?

Comment: This needs a little more detail. Are you trying to center the entire menu vertically based on available screen height? Right now you have a vertical list of horizontally-centered links. https://jsfiddle.net/vfyeL6er/